# django recurrence--get the last instance of a recurrence field

Tags: django

I need help on django recurrence. I am trying to get the next and last instance from a model recurrence field as shown:

`course = Course.objects.all()
 for c in course:
    occurrence = c.recurrences.occurrences()
    print(occurrence[0])
    print(occurrence[-1])`

This approach works but it is extremely slow. Here is the [comment](http://django-recurrence.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/recurrence_field.html#using-recurrencefield) from the recurrence package author and suggests to use recurrences **between** two dates, but as I need the last instance which in some cases is infinite(end year as 9999) it's not helping with the performance.

Is there any better alternative to fetch the next and last instances from recurring field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main culprit is the usage of `occurrence = c.recurrences.occurrences()` on rules with no end dates defined. It has to build a Python object with starting date and till year 9999 which is very very large and bad for performance.

Usually recurrence fields are saved like this in a table: 
`RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;UNTIL=20180315T040000Z;BYMONTHDAY=15`

Let's say the recurrence field name as recurrences. Then instead of doing `occurrence = c.recurrences.occurrences()` for all records, first check for **until** field in each recurrence field. If it exists then it means there is an end day. If there is an end day `occurrence = c.recurrences.occurrences()` builds a small python object (similar to using **between**) or else final instance will be with year 9999 and in which case you don't need to use the occurrences() call.

I tested this and is fast.

```
course = Course.objects.all()
for c in course:
    if c.recurrences.rrules[0].until is None:
        print('No End date')
    else:
        occurrence = c.recurrences.occurrences()
        print(occurrence[0])
        print(occurrence[-1])
```